# Is there a way to get a list of parent objects from a child object query?

Tags: apex, soql, relationships

I have a problem. I need to be able to return properties if they have opportunities in "test". There isn't a relationship from property down to opportunity. But there is a relationship from opportunity up to property.

(Hope im saying that right)

Anyways, is there a way to get properties if they have opportunities in a certain category?

```
@AuraEnabled   
        public static List <Opportunity> searchProperty(String searchString) 
        {
            //query opportunities. Put project name in a list. return the list.
                String searching = searchString + '%';
                List <Opportunity> returnList = new List <Opportunity> ();
                List <Opportunity> lstOfProperties = [select Property__r.name, name from opportunity
                                                      where recordtype.name in ('Test') 
                                    and Property__r.Name LIKE: searching and Probability not in (0,5,100)
                                    order by Property__r.Name].Property__r.Name;

               for (Opportunity acc: lstOfProperties) 
               {
                 returnList.add(acc);
               }
                 system.debug(returnList);
                 return returnList;     
       }
```

Comment: Opportunity is parent and property is child ?

Comment: Opportunity has a lookup relationship to property but property doesn't have a relationship to opportunity. This would make property the parent i think, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There isn't a relationship from property down to opportunity. But
>   there is a relationship from opportunity up to property.

This sentence does not make much sense. Instead you can say which object is Parent and which object is Child - And if necessary, you can also mention whether the relationship is lookup or master-detail. **In your case, Property is parent.**

Now coming to your problem, you can use below query to return properties which has related `test` opportunities:

```
List<Property__c> propertiesWithTestOpps = [
    SELECT Id, Name
    FROM Property__c 
    WHERE Id IN (SELECT Property__c 
                 FROM Opportunity 
                 WHERE recordtype.name in ('Test'))
];
```

Assuming lookup field name in opportunity is `Property__c` and also the object name of property is `Property__c`.

Comment: So both of those are correct, and i get what you mean. If theres a relationship between one theres a relationship between both. But using your line of code i get ```Invalid type: Schema.Property```

Comment: As i said *assuming* api name is Property__c. What is the object api name of property object?

Comment: I apologize i had a typo